# Alternatives to the terms 'Hinayana' and 'Mahayana'?

Tags: mahayana, hinayana

Where does the terms 'Hinayana' and 'Mahayana' come from? Who made them up?

They are often translated as "lesser vehicle" and "greater vehicle". I wonder about this translation. Is it correct? I think it sounds a bit degrading, as if Mahayana is somehow greater or better than Hinayana.

Are there better terms with which to speak about what is generally called 'Hinayana' and 'Mahayana'?

Comment: This question could be on-topic here, but there's already a topic [Is there a better term than Hinayana that we should be using?](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/231/254) on meta.

Comment: Maybe re-title it to "Where does the terms 'Hinayana' and 'Mahayana' come from?" -- do we have this question answered here?